Connecting ArcGIS Pro to PostgreSQL Databases with Mixed Case Naming Conventions
We’re working with QGIS connected to PostgreSQL, and the data is huge—more than 5 million features. We decided to use ArcGIS Enterprise Pro, and we need it to connect to these QGIS (PostgreSQL) databases. Once connected, we plan to create WebApps, Dashboards, etc., for monitoring our data in ArcGIS, which we find better than QGIS (there is no significant difference). The big issue is that these PostgreSQL databases have mixed upper and lower case naming, including database names, schema names, table names, and even field names. It's challenging to convert the entire structure of these databases, along with all the data, to lowercase. Additionally, there are more than 50 QGIS project files connected to these tables, so changing the table names would corrupt the project files (resulting in the red triangle indicating changes in the data source).
Is there any method to connect ArcGIS Pro to these mixed upper-lower case databases?
Here’s what I've tried:

Creating a new view database with lowercase names (database name,schema name, tables, fields), and then creating view tables using SELECT * FROM the original databases that have mixed upper-lower case letters. This didn’t work because I couldn’t get data from multiple databases (not the same database).
I tried creating view tables in the same database with lowercase field names, but I still couldn’t connect to the database because it has uppercase letters.


I can't connect to a database that have mixed upper-lower letter in ArcGIS

This question is similar to: ArcGIS Pro cannot read SQL Server databases with "-" in their name. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Because there is no benefit in keeping the mixed case names in PostGIS, it is simply best to do the job once and convert the names into lowercase. It hurts once but then you can forget the whole issue.

i knew the best approch is to go with changing the names to lower case but can you imagin huge database with huge data and more than 50 field in each schema

You will use more time with finding some poor workaround. Amount of data does not matter with ALTER SCHEMA and ALTER TABLE.

I do not know if I am allowed to post here what ChatGPT suggests. I will delete this answer if that is against any rules.
A SQL query that renames all mixed case column names into lower case can be generated with a single SQL command:
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' || table_name || ' RENAME "' || column_name || '" TO ' || lower(column_name) || ';'
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'your_schema_name'  -- replace with your schema name, e.g., 'public'
AND table_name = 'your_table_name'        -- replace with your table name
AND column_name != lower(column_name);    -- only columns with mixed-case names

Same approach can be used for schemas and table names.
